# Retrieving all items from one table that is not in other table with Linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have one boat class and a rent boat class.

Boat class:

```
public class Boat
{
    [Key]
    public int BoatID { get; set; }

    public string BoatName { get; set; }
}
```

RentBoat class:

```
public class RentBoat
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int RentBoatID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Boat")]
    public int BoatID { get; set; }

    public bool IsOnRent { get; set; }

    public virtual  Boat Boat { get; set; }
}
```

I want to get all Boats from the database that is not in the RentBoats table.

My not working code so far:

```
using (var db = new BoatContext())
{
    return db.Boats.Where(boat => !db.RentBoats.Any(x => x.IsOnRent == false)).ToList();

     //(from boats in db.Boats
     //           where !db.RentBoats.Any(x => x.IsOnRent == false)
     //           select boats).ToList();
}
```

Haven't got any of the queries to work properly. Both of them return all the boats even if I have one item in the RentBoat table with the IsOnRent column set to 1 which is supposed to represent true in the database.

Comment: Is it on EntityFramwork ? Is there a navigation property from Boat to RendBoat ? If not, can it be add ?

Comment: Yes its EF. No navigation property from Boat to RentBoat. Yes it can be added. Do you think I should to make it easier to query? How would that query look?

Comment: I think. Query seems look like db.Boats.Where(boat => !boat.Rents.Any(rent => rent.IsOnRent))

Comment: Yes. but when i add a item to the RentBoat table dont I have to update two tables if the IsOnRent is located in the Boat tabel. Is there a way of traversing to the Boat table and modify the Boat => column: IsOnRent while adding an item to the RentBoat. I want to keep the querys to a minimum.

Comment: IsOnRent is always in the BoatRent entity. Rents is a navigation property to associated RentBot entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your LINQ to the following:

```
db.Boats.Where(boat => !db.RentBoats.Any(x => x.BoatID == boat.BoatID &&  
x.IsOnRent == true)).ToList();
```

Your current query is trying to get Boats in case if all boats are on rent.

Comment: Thank you Sir! that worked great!. The Id I totally forgot. Realized that I put `!db.Boats` and ` false` in the same statement. Thanks again!